# Map Fragment loading slowly

Tags: android, google-maps

I put a **Map Fragment inside dashboard fragment** shown in image below:

[image: Dashboard Fragment]

To view the image clearly https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcxLB.jpg

whenever i am on **home fragment** and click on **dashboard fragment** it takes 3-4 sec (at the first time) and 1-2 sec

here is the code of dashboard fragment

```
    class DashboardFragment :
    BaseFragment<DashboardViewModel, FragmentDashboardBinding, WeatherRepository>(),
    GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback {

    private var map: GoogleMap? = null
    private var cameraPosition: CameraPosition? = null

    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

    private val defaultLocation = LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085)
    private var locationPermissionGranted = false
    private var lastKnownLocation: Location? = null
    private var weatherData: WeatherData? = null

    private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<NestedScrollView>

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            lastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION)
            cameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION)
            weatherData = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_WEATHER_DATA)
        }
        Log.e("Weather Data", weatherData.toString())

            fusedLocationProviderClient =
                LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())
            val mapFragment =
                childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.myMap) as SupportMapFragment?
            mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this@DashboardFragment)


        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding.root.bottomSheet)
        bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object :
            BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) { /*handle onSlide*/ }

            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                when (newState) {
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> {
                        binding.root.bottomSheet.background =
                            (ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.round))
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> {
                        binding.root.bottomSheet.background =
                            (ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.edge))
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING -> {
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> {
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> {
                    }
                    else -> {
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        viewModel.weatherResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            when (it) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    updateUi(binding.root, it.value)
                    weatherData = it.value
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireContext(),
                        "Damn, Failed To Load Data",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        })

    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        map?.let { map ->
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION, map.cameraPosition)
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, lastKnownLocation)
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap) {
        this.map = map
        map.setOnMapClickListener(this)
        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this)
        map.setOnCameraIdleListener(this)
        getLocationPermission()
        updateLocationUI()
        getDeviceLocation()
    }

    var marker: Marker? = null
    override fun onMapClick(point: LatLng) {
        if (marker == null){
        marker = map?.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
                .position(point)
                .title("${point.latitude.toString()},${point.longitude.toString()} is the location")
        )
        } else {
            marker!!.position  = point
            marker!!.title = "${point.latitude.toString()},${point.longitude.toString()} is the location"
        }
        viewModel.getWeather(
            point.latitude.toString(),
            point.longitude.toString(),
            app_id
        )
        if (bottomSheetBehavior.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
        else
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "click $point", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onMapLongClick(point: LatLng) {
        try {
            val manager: FragmentManager =
                (this.context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
            CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment().show(manager, CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment.TAG)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("❤", e.printStackTrace().toString())
        }
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onCameraIdle() {
        //if(!::map.isInitialized) return
        //cameraTextView.text = map.cameraPosition.toString()
        //Toast.makeText(this.context, "camera idle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private fun updateLocationUI() {
        if (map == null) {
            return
        }
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                map?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                map?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
            } else {
                map?.isMyLocationEnabled = false
                map?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
                lastKnownLocation = null
                getLocationPermission()
            }
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.message, e)
        }
    }

    private fun getDeviceLocation() {
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                val locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        lastKnownLocation = task.result
                        if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                            map?.moveCamera(
                                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                    LatLng(
                                        lastKnownLocation!!.latitude,
                                        lastKnownLocation!!.longitude
                                    ), DEFAULT_ZOOM.toFloat()
                                )
                            )
                            viewModel.getWeather(
                                lastKnownLocation!!.latitude.toString(),
                                lastKnownLocation!!.longitude.toString(),
                                app_id
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.")
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.exception)
                        map?.moveCamera(
                            CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newLatLngZoom(defaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM.toFloat())
                        )
                        map?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.message, e)
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Some exception occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun getLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            locationPermissionGranted = true
        } else {
            requestPermissions(
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        locationPermissionGranted = false
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION -> {

                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    locationPermissionGranted = true
                }
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI()
    }

    override fun getViewModal() = DashboardViewModel::class.java

    override fun getFragmentBinding(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?
    ) = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    override fun getFragmentRepository() =
        WeatherRepository(remoteDataSource.buildApi(WeatherApi::class.java))


    companion object {
        private val TAG = DashboardFragment::class.java.simpleName
        private const val DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15
        private const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1
        private const val KEY_CAMERA_POSITION = "camera_position"
        private const val KEY_LOCATION = "location"
        private const val KEY_WEATHER_DATA = "weather_data"
        const val app_id = "*******api********"
    }
}
```

even if i comment the whole code it the **onActivityCreated()** method still the lag occurs.

I used the code from the official **Google Maps Platform Documentation**, still the example app they use don't lags like my app.

Any help will be appreciated.